# How can software that doesn't natively support JACK be made to work with it?

Tags: audio, jack, voip, voice

Audacity, for example, can be switched to JACK if needed. What about software that can't but can be switched to alsa?

Answer (score 0):

A solution proved at the following address works well
http://www.penguinproducer.com/Blog/2011/11/jack-alsa-bridge-kit